# ActionPerformed function working but if statement in public static void main not working

Tags: java

I can get this to work with it all in the same file but I'm new to using multiple classes in different files. I've left out the imports to shorten the code.

Here is the code:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        handler handler = new handler();
        Login Login = new Login();
    
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>();
    
        users.add("123");
        passwords.add("123");
    
        if (handler.buttonPress) {
            String userInput = Login.userText.getText();
            String passwordInput = String.valueOf(Login.passwordText.getPassword());
                    
            if (users.contains(userInput)) {
            
                int userNo = users.indexOf(userInput);
                String password = passwords.get(userNo);
            
                if (passwordInput.equals(password)) {
                    Login.outcomeLabel.setText("Login Successfull!");
                } 
                else {
                    Login.outcomeLabel.setText("Username or Password not recognised");
                }
            }
            else {
                Login.outcomeLabel.setText("Username or Password not recognised");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Login.java:

```
public class Login {

    Main main = new Main();
    handler handler = new handler();

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField userText;
    JPasswordField passwordText;
    JLabel outcomeLabel;

    public Login() {
    
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 200));
    
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("Login");
    
        panel.setLayout(null);
    
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 85, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);
    
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setBounds(80, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);
    
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 85, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
    
        passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(80, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);
    
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(80, 80, 80, 25);
        loginButton.addActionListener(handler);
        panel.add(loginButton);
    
        outcomeLabel = new JLabel();
        outcomeLabel.setBounds(30, 120, 300, 25);
        panel.add(outcomeLabel);
    
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

handler.java:

```
public class handler implements ActionListener {

    Login Login = new Login();

    boolean buttonPress;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent loginButton) {
        buttonPress = true;
    }
}
```

So the action listener is setting the Boolean to true but the if statement is main isn't recognising it.

Comment: Why don't you move the logic inside the `actionPerformed` method?

Comment: Bunches of serious problems here but the main ones: JFrames are not modal, and you're checking program state before the user has had a chance to change it, and secondly, you're creating multiple instances of classes, and not checking the state of the important ones, the ones involved with the user.

Comment: So, if you need a Swing GUI window to act modally, to block program flow until handled, then create and display a model JDialog, not a JFrame.  Next, only create *one* single instance of each of your key classes above, not multiple as you are doing, and pass those instances as parameters to where they are needed.

Comment: How would I go about passing the instances?

Comment: Your code above also causes a StackOverflowError

Comment: Please comment back if you have questions about my answer. Also, please have a look at the [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) link to know what to do when someone answers your question on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with this code:

1. You get a StackOverflowError due to circular references causing recursion: Your Login class creates a new handler instance, while handler creates a new Login instance, and this will repeat forever (or until you run out of stack memory).
2. You are trying to extract and use a value, here the buttonPress boolean value, before the user has had a chance to change it. This is because a JFrame is not a modal window and so does not halt program flow as a modal dialog would, and so you you display your JFrame and then immediately attempt to use the buttonPress field before the user has even had a chance to interact with the GUI.
3. Mixing linear static main method paradigm programming with event-driven Swing GUI programming in a bad way. Best to stick with one or the other.
4. Other less major issues are present including class names not following Java conventions (handler should be "Handler") and use of null layouts which make for GUI's that are difficult to maintain and do not look good on all platforms.

Instead:

- Create single instances of your key classes and pass them where needed rather than creating multiple instances in different classes

e.g.,

```
class Login {
    // Main main = new Main();   // serves no purpose
    // handler handler = new handler();  // a circular reference
    handler handler;
    
    //
    
    public void setHandler(handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }
```

- If you need a modal window, display a modal dialog, such as a modal JDialog
- Stick with either a linear non-GUI programming paradigm or an event-driven GUI paradigm to avoid lots of headaches and code that just doesn't mesh well. Better still, separate your program logic from the view (user interaction), so that the same logic/data portion can be used in either an event-driven GUI or a non-event-driven linear program.
- Learn and follow Java naming conventions and follow them, including giving classes names that start with upper-case letters and fields names that start with lower-case letters. This will make your code much easier for others to understand.